# D3.js - Get all possible child elements for a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js to create a Tree structure. The application I am developing requires me to show the immediate children & the total children for each node. I can find the immediate children using d.children.length , but is it possible to get the total child elements(upto leaf) below a node ? If yes how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a recursive function such as:

```
function getDescendants(node) {
    if(!node.children) {
        return 0;
    }
    var total = 0;
    node.children.forEach(function(d) {
        total += 1+getDescendants(d);
    }) 
    return total;
}
```

The goal is to go through each node and count it's descendance (including itself).

An alternative method is to use the `reduce` function in order to write less code.

```
function getDescendantsReduce(node) {
    if(!node.children) {
        return 0;
    }
    return node.children.reduce(function(c,d) {
        // c is the accumulator, we start with c=0 
        // d is the node of the array that gets computed 
        return c+1+getDescendants(b)
    },0)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hFTN8/16/

---

**EDIT**

In "modern" javascript, the function would be:

```
const getDescendantsReduce = (node) => node.children
  ? node.children.reduce( (c,b) => c+1+getDescendants(b), 0)
  : 0;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the instant reply & the fiddle too.